# Why doesn't the isEnabled for the ToggleButton work in Android?

Tags: android, isenabled, android-togglebutton

I just defined a ToggleButton variable, found the view by the id, set activated to false, and set a OnClickListener. In the onClick method, I checked if it was enabled in a if statement. If it was enabled, then it should have logged it, but I checked in Console and LogCat, and it didn't display anything. Here's my code:

```
tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.onoff);
    tb.setActivated(false);
    tb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(tb.isEnabled()){
                Log.d("", "activated");
            }else if(!tb.isEnabled()){
                Log.d("", "deactivated");
            }
        }
    });
```

I don't know how to do the 'code inside text' thing (like onClick should have a gray box over it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public boolean isEnabled ()
```

This method is inherited from base class view, which mostly defines whether it is user intractable or not.

You will need to use ***isChecked()*** method to determine whether ToggleButton is on or off.

Update your code as:

```
tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.onoff);
tb.setActivated(false);
tb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(((ToggleButton)v).isChecked()){
            Log.d("", "activated");
        }else{
            Log.d("", "deactivated");
        }
    }
});
```

or second way

in your xml code

```
<ToggleButton 
android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textOn="Vibrate on"
android:textOff="Vibrate off"
android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>
```

in your activity

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
// Is the toggle on?
boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

if (on) {
    // Enable vibrate
} else {
    // Disable vibrate
}
}
```

Comment: Er...still doesn't work...LogCat still completely blank.

Comment: updated the answer try first way...if doesnt work second way has to work :)